# A question about IMO 1986 P3

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, combinatorial-game-theory

> **IMO 1986 P3**: To each vertex of a pentagon, we assign an integer $x_i$ with sum $s=\sum x_i>0$. If $x,y,z$ are numbers assigned to three successive vertices and if $y<0$, then we replace $(x,y,z)$ by $(x+y,-y,y+z)$. This step is repeated as long as there is a $y<0$. Decide if the algorithm always stops. (Most difficult problem of the IMO).

After generating some examples, I found the following pattern: if $s$ is the sum of the integers at the vertices, then $\sum_{i=1}^5 (s-x_i)^2$ is a **weakly** decreasing function. Is this true? The solution, which was apparently given by only 11 students in the world, uses the function $\sum (x_i-x_{i+2})^2$, and shows that it is strictly decreasing. Moreover, if the function $\sum_{i=1}^5 (s-x_i)^2$ is indeed weakly decreasing, does it become strictly decreasing every $j$ iterations, where $j>1$?

Comment: @saulspatz- Edited, thanks

Comment: Can you add the proof that your sum $\sum_{i=1}^5\,(s-x_i)^2$ is weakly decreasing?  Maybe we will notice something and be able to help out.  However, in my opinion, this is not a natural choice.  In this kind of problems, I would expect that a good semivariant would measure how much the data $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_5$ are different.  Something like $\sum |x_i-x_j|$ or $\sum (x_i-x_j)^2$ would be a good choice.  And it is no surprising at all that $\sum (x_i-x_{i+2})^2$ turns out to be a good semivariant.

Comment: @Batominovski What is the definition of semivariant, please?  I can find a few uses of the term by googling, but no definition.

Comment: Well, if you have a combinatorial process, a *semivariance* is a function that takes your current state and returns some real number (usually a positive integer).  We want this function to either increase only or decrease only (weakly or strongly), as the process progresses further.  (This is why the prefix *semi-* is there.  The change is in only one direction, instead of both up and down.)  This is in contrast with an *invariance*, which does not change as progresses are made.

Comment: @Batominovski Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked that $y:=\sum\limits_{i=1}^5\,(s-x_i)^2$ is not even a semivariant (apparently, the correct ending is *t*, not *ce*).  For example, if we start with $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5):=(1,-3,1,1,1)$, then at the beginning, we have $$y=0^2+0^2+4^2+0^2+0^2=16\,.$$
The only allowed move is $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)\mapsto (-2,3,-2,1,1)$.  At this point, 
$$y=0^2+3^2+(-2)^2+3^2+0^2=22\,.$$
Therefore, $y=\sum\limits_{i=1}^5\,(s-x_i)^2$ is not a good function to be used.

---

For the sake of completeness, I shall supply a full answer to this IMO problem.  I shall use the OP's hint.  However, there is another semivariant, but it is very ugly.  This semivariant is in the hidden box below.

> The ugly semivariant ($u$ for **u**gly) I know is $$u:=\sum_{i=1}^5\,|x_i|+\sum_{i=1}^5\,|x_i+x_{i+1}|+\sum_{i=1}^5\,|x_i+x_{i+1}+x_{i+2}|+\sum_{i=1}^5\,|x_i+x_{i+1}+x_{i+2}+x_{i+3}|\,.$$  If you feel somewhat bored today, then please have fun with this semivariant.

To not cause any confusion, suppose the $k$-th state is denoted by $\left(x_1^k,x_2^k,x_3^k,x_4^k,x_5^k\right)$.  We shall prove that
$$z^k:=\sum_{i=1}^5\,\left(x_i^k-x_{i+2}^k\right)^2$$
is a (strong) semivariant.  (The indices in the sum above are considered modulo $5$.)  That is, $z^k>z^{k+1}$ as long as the game has not terminated.  I should like to note that $s=\sum\limits_{i=1}^5\,x_i^k$ at all possible $k$.

Now, suppose without loss of generality that, at the $k$-th step, the transformation into the $(k+1)$-st step is given by $$\left(x_1^{k+1},x_2^{k+1},x_3^{k+1},x_4^{k+1},x_5^{k+1}\right)=\left(x_1^{k}+x_2^{k},-x_2^k,x_2^k+x_3^k,x_4^k,x_5^k\right)\,.$$
Hence,
$$\begin{align}z^{k+1}-z^k
&=(-x_2^k-x_4^k)^2-(x_2^k-x_4^k)^2+(x_2^k+x_3^k-x_5^k)^2-(x_3^k-x_5^k)^2
\\
&\phantom{aaaa}+(x_4^k-x_1^k-x_2^k)^2-(x_4^k-x_1^k)^2+(x_5^k+x_2^k)^2-(x_5^k-x_2^k)^2
\\
&=4x_2^kx_4^k+2(x_2^k)^2+2x_2^k(x_3^k-x_5^k)-2x_2^k(x_4^k-x_1^k)+4x_2^kx_5^k
\\
&=2x_2^k(x_1^k+x_2^k+x_3^k+x_4^k+x_5^k)=2s\,x_2^k\,.
\end{align}$$
Since this move is only allowed when $x_2^k<0$ and since $s>0$, we conclude that $z^{k+1}-z^k<0$.

Comment: I suppose semivariance is "the state of being a semivariant," or "the quality of a semivariant," those it's hard to say what either of those phrases mean. :-)